# In a demonstration of integration, a difficult simplification

Tags: integration

I am working with a demonstration broadcasting by MIT on [integration](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-3-the-definite-integral-and-its-applications/part-a-definition-of-the-definite-integral-and-first-fundamental-theorem/session-43-definite-integrals/) But i could not understand the last part.

I have this:

[image: simplification step]

BUT,

I have no idea how to arrive from the term in red to the term in blue.  I understand that in the second step (b) I divide all the expression by n3.(n cube)

Can some one help me understand please?  Thanks...

There is here some mistake because in b.  is not reflected the division by n^3 in the last term (in red).

In order to rectify this and clarify is better if we include this operation and reflect every step of the simplification:

[image]

Here I correct the mistake in b and add b1 for clarifying the step-by-step solution.

Comment: Actually the red text is wrong, it must read $\dfrac13\,\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}$, which is equal to the blue text $\dfrac13\bigl(1+\dfrac1n\bigr)^3$.

Comment: Right! But, how do you arrive to that? Meaning the transition from (a) to (c)?  Can you help me with that please?

Comment: Unsurprisingly the MIT lecturer actually **does** divide by $n^3$ the RHS as well, just as in your b.1 (except that his LHS is correct while the LHS of b.1 is wrong). Makes one wonder where you got this b.